# Deleting the only answer to the question

Tags: discussion, moderation, link-only-answers

There is a question which had only one answer (and answer was upvoted). The answer was link only, but it was found useful by community and link is alive since 2009. Recently this answer was deleted by moderator. Does our community prefer to leave question without any answer at all instead of leaving it with one link only answer?

I'm intentionally will not provide any links or screenshots, so it's not a rant of any kind, I just want to know the answer.

Comment: If the link was outmoded, broken or otherwise just saying, "Check [this](https://www.example.com) out!", then I don't see a reason for it to *persist*, really.

Comment: if the link is dead, the contents of the link were needed to answer the question, said parts weren't quoted in the answer and you can't get an achieve snapshot then yes. rather an unanswered question than one answered with a rotten answer

Comment: It was discussed so many times before. Don't compare SO year 2017 to SO year 2009

Comment: That was alive link to a code example with detailed explanations, and now it's just invisible for our readers

Comment: Why not write your own answer? Make sure you use your own words though.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think this is not about *his* answer, just an answer he saw. Quoting Konstantin: *"I'm intentionally will not provide any links or screenshots, so it's not a rant of any kind, I just want to know the answer."*

Comment: Link to the question and deleted answer please. And if it is as you say, the answer should have been edited into shape by adding those details found in the link. You could have done that, anyone else could have done that, even anonymous visitors could have done that. Still since 2009 nobody cared.

Comment: @rene remember, no links. I've already flagged that answer with explanations.

Comment: @Mistalis I was talking about the general case. He must care enough about the topic and the old answer to see that its gone. If that's the case write a new answer that's not link only.

Comment: @mistalis Okay, okay - it was mine answer. It' was posted very long ago in 2012 linking to article from 2009.

Comment: For now I've just reposted link as comment and I'm fine with that. But I really don't like the attitude

Comment: Even converting that to community wiki answer is better than just deleting it silently

Comment: The 'answer' was *There is great BalusC article with a sample of such file download servlet and a lot of explanations about it's work principles.*. That is an excellent example of a link-only answer; without the link it is entirely meaningless. It received a grand total of 2 upvotes in the 3.5 years it has been on the site, which really is an indicator it wasn't all that well received.

Comment: And you forgot to mention that this is **your own answer**. That is a rather **important detail** in a discussion like this. As it stands your question implies it was anyone's answer, one you are upset to see go because it was helpful to you, but because it is your own answer, you are hardly an objective observer here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's because this question is more about this _kind_ of answers and not that particular answer itself.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov: it is a link-only answer, it should be treated like any other link-only answer. It doesn't matter if it is the only answer to the question.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov how will making it community wiki help? Given that you apparently can't be bothered to improve it, despite thinking it's good enough to make a fuss on meta about (and now despite it being *your own answer* - although you have plenty of rep to edit it either way, and CW or not) why do you think anyone else can? Be the change you want to see in the world!

Comment: Honestly, you guys are taking this "link only" answer crusade way too far.  Why delete what may be the only answer to someone's question out of a misguided sense of purity?  If it bugs you so much, why not expand it into a non-"link only" answer and actually do some good?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Does our community prefer to leave question without any answer at all instead of leaving it with one link only answer?

Yes.

Link only answers are just lazy <s>crap</s> low quality content that leaves visitors with an awful user experience. This site is about finding the answer to your questions **HERE**. Not by following a link only to find out you end-up at best at an lengthy blog article where you still have to piece together what you're looking for, second best the link is dead and at worst the linked site turned into a cat-gifs collection.

For link only answers the first call to action is to fix it. Edit the relevant parts of the linked material in the answer. Keep in mind that *everybody* can edit. If that is not feasible, leave a comment for the OP and when no action is taken, flag for deletion.

In the early days the quality standards were different and a lot of link only answers were left in that state. If nobody cared for 5 or 6 years to fix that, I see no problem in deleting such answers and if that leaves the question unanswered then maybe the question isn't that good after all.  Close vote and down vote so it can be [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)-ed or deleted by users with [delete privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Because with that action you make sure that the good stuff is easier to find.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. It's clear enough now.

Comment: I completely disagree. Surely cat-gifs would be the best outcome?